# C# refugee seeks a bit of Java collections help

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I need to store key/value info in some type of collection.  In C#, I'd define a dictionary like this:

```
var entries = new Dictionary<string, int>();
entries.Add("Stop me", 11);
entries.Add("Feed me", 12);
entries.Add("Walk me", 13);
```

Then I would access the values so:

```
int value = entries["Stop me"];
```

How do I do this in Java?  I've seen examples with `ArrayList`, but I'd like the solution with generics, if possible.

Comment: C# refugee? Isn't that a state of sin? :))

Comment: More like an epiphany :)

Comment: ArrayList is a sequence or list-like construct (not a Dictionary), although it is generic

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use a `Map`

```
Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
m.put("Stop me", 11);
Integer i = m.get("Stop me"); // i == 11
```

Note that on the last line, I could have said:

```
int i = m.get("Stop me");
```

Which is shorthand for (with Java's auto-unboxing):

```
int i = m.get("Stop me").intValue()
```

If there is no value in the map at the given key, the `get` returns `null` and this expression throws a `NullPointerException`. Hence it's **always** a good idea to use the *boxed type* `Integer` in this case

Answer (score 7):

Use a `java.util.Map`.  There are several implementations:

- `HashMap`: O(1) lookup, does not maintain order of keys
- `TreeMap`: O(log n) lookup, maintains order of keys, so you can iterate over them in a guaranteed order
- `LinkedHashMap`: O(1) lookup, iterates over keys in the order they were added to the map.

You use them like:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("Stop me", 11);
map.put("Feed me", 12);

int value = map.get("Stop me");
```

For added convenience working with collections, have a look at the [Google Collections library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). It's excellent.

Comment: Repeat comment: Your last line is dangerous: if there is no value in the map at that key, it will throw a NullPointerException because of your use of unboxing

Comment: There is a value in the map with that key! But to clarify, you would first check for a missing key by calling the map's contains method and/or checking that the result of get(key) is not null. The latter is less likely, since it is poor practice to pass mulls between objects.

Comment: Oops. I mean "nulls" not "mulls".

Comment: It would have deserved a +1 for Map explanation if the O's were correct. HashMap and LinkedHashMap provide constant-time - O(1) - performance, not O(n). Their worst-case performance (i.e. all objects have same hash) is O(n)

Comment: I realised I'd mistyped them and found you'd just beat me to the correction!

Answer (score 6):

You use a [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java.

Note that you can't use `int` (or any other primitive type) as a generic type parameter, but because of autoboxing, it still behaves *almost* as if it were a `Map<String, int>` instead of a `Map<String, Integer>`. (You don't want to be doing a lot of autoboxing in performance-sensitive code, though.)

```
Map<String, Integer> entries = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
entries.put("Stop me", 11);
entries.put("Feed me", 12);
entries.put("Walk me", 13);
int value = entries.get("Stop me"); // if you know it exists
// If you're not sure whether the map contains a value, it's better to do:
Integer boxedValue = entries.get("Punch me");
if (boxedValue != null) {
    int unboxedValue = boxedValue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your last line is dangerous: if there is no value in the map at that key, it will throw a NullPointerException because of your use of unboxing

Comment: Yes, good point. Autoboxing is very nice, but unboxing doesn't really help that much.

Comment: Roll on the @NotNull annotation

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for something like [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want a `HashMap`, which is the Java version of C# `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Stop Me", 11);
map.put("Feed Me", 12);
map.put("Walk Me", 13);
Integer x; // little hack
int value = (x = a.get("aaa")) == null? 0 : x;
```

as alternative you can try Enum:

```
enum Action {

    STOP(11),
    FEED(12),
    WALK(13);

    private final int value;

    private Action(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Action valueOf(int value) {
        for (Action action : values()) {
            if (action.value == value) {
                return action;
            }
        }

        return null; // or a null-object
    }
}
```

test:

```
public void action() {
    Action action = Action.valueOf("FEED"); 
    // or Action.FEED for more compile-time safety
    int value = action.value();
    // instantiating by code 
    Action walk = Action.valueOf(13);
}
```

Comment: Repeat Comment: Your last line is dangerous: if there is no value in the map at that key, it will throw a NullPointerException because of your use of unboxing

Comment: Let's hope the user has names that are legal java identifiers.

Comment: Having an Enum where null is somehow a value, isn't really an enum. A enum is supposed to enumerate the possible values